# Trouble with Angular Resource Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting started with the meanjs stack, and have reached a bit of a headscratcher that I don't have the understanding to google properly.

I have the following files:
**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

  angular
    .module('students')
    .controller('StudentsListController', StudentsListController);

  StudentsListController.$inject = ['StudentsService'];

  function StudentsListController(StudentsService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.students = StudentsService.query();
  }
}());
```

Using this service, I am able to get an array of Student objects in the list-students controller, next:

**list-students.client.controller.js**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('students')
    .factory('StudentsService', StudentsService);

  StudentsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function StudentsService($resource) {
    return $resource('api/students/:studentId', {
      studentId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
}());
```

This works as intended.
What I don't understand, is why when I try to use the same service in another controller, it seems to fail to inject, leaving me with an undefined StudentsServices variable.
What gives?

**students.client.controller.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

  // Students controller
  angular
    .module('students')
    .controller('StudentsController', StudentsController);  

  StudentsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Authentication',   'StudentsService'];

  function StudentsController ($scope, $state, Authentication, student, StudentsService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.authentication = Authentication;
    vm.student = student;
    vm.students = StudentsService.query();
...
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inject is wrong.

```
'$scope', '$state', 'Authentication',   'StudentsService'
```

But you're telling the controller to expect

```
$scope, $state, Authentication, student, StudentsService
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, per 
[AngularJS: Factory is always undefined when injected in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327796/angularjs-factory-is-always-undefined-when-injected-in-controller)

It was that my injections need to be in the same order as the params passed into the controller function.

Aha!